# react state variables inconsistent

Tags: reactjs

I am fairly new to React coming from a JS & Java background. I am still understanding react `state` properties and have two code samples, one which compiles and one which does not. In the first, I establish the class' state as having one variable `str` and I work with this variable. This code does not work. In the second, the variable is named `value`, and it works. Is it not possible to have a variable under a different name or more than one variable in `react`? Thank you!!

**Side Note:** The term "works" in this context is the difference between being able to type into the text field or not.

Form Code (Works):

```
class SomeOtherForm extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          str: '',
      };
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleValueChanged(event) {
      this.setState({str: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Y.. ' + this.state.str);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type='text' value={this.state.str} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </label>
          <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
      </form>
    );
  }

}
```

Form Code (Doesn't Work):

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SomeOtherForm` there are a few mishaps:

- You're calling `this.handleChange` for the `onChange` event, but this method doesn't exist (it needs to be changed from `handleValueChanged` to `handleChange`)
- You haven't bound both handlers to the constructor (you need to add `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);`)

Fixed:

```
class SomeOtherForm extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { str: '' }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      str: event.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    alert(`Yo shit isssss.. ${this.state.str}`)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input 
            type='text' 
            value={this.state.str} 
            onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
          <input 
            type='submit' 
            value='Submit'/>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you named the function `handleValueChanged` NOT `handleChange`...

**This will fix your problem:**

```
<input type='text' value={this.state.str} onChange={this.handleValueChanged}/>
```

As a side note state in react is an objectand thats it. So referring to state like this

> I establish the class' state as having one variable str and I work
>   with this variable

Isnt actually technically accurate and makes things sound more confusing than they are.

Answer (score 1):

It's totally possible manage different variables in state.

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    name: '',
    lastname: ''
  }
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
}
handleSubmit (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log(this.state)
}
handleChange (event) {
  const { name, value } = event.target
  this.setState({
    [name]: value
  })
}
render () {
  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <input
      name='name'
      value={this.state.name}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
    />
    <input
      name='lastname'
      value={this.state.lastname}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
    />
  </form>
}
```

> Pay attention to the name of the inputs they should be the same as the variables in your state.